# How does gravity's space time distortion access energy to induce freefall?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity

An observer, standing on top of a building, has a gravity switch (use your imagination) which allows him to turn gravity on and off.  He turns the switch off, then releases a pool ball over the edge of the building at 100' above the street below.  Presumably, both the ball and the earth have a common velocity in some direction and therefore are at rest relative to one another.  The ball hovers at 100'.
Then he turns on the gravity switch.  My understanding is that the gravity will then distort spacetime between the ball and the earth.  This distortion causes a change in the relationship between distance and time, thus inducing motion and acceleration between these two masses, and the ball will go into freefall.
Since Einstein says that gravity is not a force in and of itself, then what is the real source of the potential energy?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "gravity switch". As to where the ball got that energy, that's simple. The observer carried it to the top of the building.

Comment: David Hammen is correct, there is no such switch. There is an analogous situation with regards to magnetism, which can be shielded, so one can construct magnetic switches of the sort that you imagine. However, turning such a switch off requires a non-trivial amount of energy because it alters the field configuration. Energy conservation holds because of the energy required to establish/remove the shield. So where you are going wrong is in naively assuming that switching gravity on/off would be a free process. In reality, you would have to pay the energy needed to remove the gravitating mass.

Comment: This is not about the switch.  It is about how a distortion in space time can induce acceleration.

Comment: The "how" is explained by the theory of general relativity, but it seems to me, that you may be asking a "What's the microscopic explanation?" question? Why do masses gravitate on the quantum level? We don't have a microscopic answer to that question at the moment, although many different hypothetical models have been proposed. With regards to the energy, it's still in the "field", except that it's not quite as straight forward to define and calculate in GR as it is in field theories that live on a flat background.

Comment: It's a question about the workings of general relativity that shouldn't require quantum physics. Most descriptions, however, refer to orbiting bodies, as opposed to bodies at rest relative to one another. It may be though that some of the ball's mass is converted to energy.

Comment: Perhaps the stress-energy-tensor is what I am looking for.

Comment: Perhaps you are right, hence I said that the how is is explained by GR... but, again, the explanation you will find there may not satisfy you as much as you think.

Comment: @user60189: the effects you descripbe persist in spacteimes where the stress energy tensor is exactly zero, such as the Schwarzschild spacetime.

Answer (score 1):

The source of the potential energy is the fact that different observers have a different notion of "stationary", because the curvature of spacetime rotates the time of one observer into the space of another.  We know from classical mechanics that energy is related to time translation symmetry, so it shouldn't be surprising that messing with the definition of time will have an energy associated with it.

Therefore, to this observer, it will look like the infalling object is picking up kinetic energy.  I should add, however, that although this simple example has a notion of energy embedded in it:

1) energy is only conserved for orbits in spacetimes with a time-translation symmetry, like the Schwarzschild or Kerr solutions.  This is true only for particles with a mass so small we can ignore gravitational radiation

2) Generally, only the total energy of spacetime is conserved, and this is true only in a special case of spacetimes known as asymptotically flat (and a few related spacetimes).

3) In these contexts, we really only talk about a total energy, rather than concerning ourselves with dividing it into kinetic and potential energy.

Comment: Thanks. Two points you make are of particular interest.   "energy is related to time translation symmetry"  and  "only the total energy of spacetime is conserved, and this is true only in a special case of spacetimes known as asymptotically flat"  .